# HP Proliant G7 hardware RAID configuration automation with ribcl

Tags: hp, hardware-raid, ilo

I have been trying to automate hardware RAID configuration of HP proliant machines before OS installation (So I can not use hpacucli)
  ssh into iLO3 doesn't have option for RAID configuration
  I use ribcl but there is no command for RAID config, however I see this
under the command **GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH**.

```
<STORAGE>
    <CONTROLLER>
        <LABEL VALUE="Controller on System Board"/>
        <STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
        <CONTROLLER_STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
        <SERIAL_NUMBER VALUE="50014380215F0070"/>
        <MODEL VALUE="HP Smart Array P420i Controller"/>
        <FW_VERSION VALUE="3.41"/>
        <DRIVE_ENCLOSURE>
            <LABEL VALUE="Port 1I Box 1"/>
            <STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
            <DRIVE_BAY VALUE="04"/>
        </DRIVE_ENCLOSURE>
        <DRIVE_ENCLOSURE>
            <LABEL VALUE="Port 2I Box 0"/>
            <STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
            <DRIVE_BAY VALUE="01"/>
        </DRIVE_ENCLOSURE>
        <LOGICAL_DRIVE>
            <LABEL VALUE="01"/>
            <STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
            <CAPACITY VALUE="68 GB"/>
            <FAULT_TOLERANCE VALUE="RAID 0"/>
            <PHYSICAL_DRIVE>
                <LABEL VALUE="Port 1I Box 1 Bay 3"/>
                <STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
                <SERIAL_NUMBER VALUE="6TA0N3SZ0000B231CYDT"/>
                <MODEL VALUE="EH0072FAWJA"/>
                <CAPACITY VALUE="68 GB"/>
                <LOCATION VALUE="Port 1I Box 1 Bay 3"/>
                <FW_VERSION VALUE="HPDH"/>
                <DRIVE_CONFIGURATION VALUE="Configured"/>
            </PHYSICAL_DRIVE>
        </LOGICAL_DRIVE>
    </CONTROLLER>
</STORAGE>
```

My question is, is there a way I modify/create this xml piece (say I have 2 Logical drive with one spare) and reboot the server it takes effect ?
If this approach is not correct are there any other ways to automate hardware raid config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We embed the `hpacucli` command onto a separate PXE image or as part of the Linux installer's `%pre` commpand set.

It also looks like you're working on a Gen8 server (according to the Smart Array P420i output above). You can leverage [Intelligent Provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features) profiles as well.

Comment: This is great. Can you give a sample %pre command for say 3 disks ? Also I googled around for hpacucli pxe image couldn't find one. Can you share the image ?

Comment: oh .. btw above xml is copied from "HP iLO 3 Scripting and Command Line Guide" we use DL580 G7.